# How can i allow user to insert location into mysql database using flask

Tags: mysql, google-maps, flask

im creating a website using python flask, in the website the user should upload locatin, rate and add a description. im having trouble with finding a method that will let the user insert google map location to MySql database. can i use only my flask app and MySql database for doing that or i need php as well?

Thank You!

Comment: What is a "Google map location"? Is it a URL, a lat/long, a full address? It has to be something and that something can be stored in a database. And, no... you don't combine python-flask and php. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of location you are looking for them to upload. If you are talking about an actual geographical location (ie a pin dropped from a [Leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) map) then you can store this in your database as two rows: latitude and longitude.

However, I suspect from your question that you instead want to identify a "place" (eg a restaurant, bar, hotel, park, landmark, house, etc) in which case lat/lon is a poor choice because there may be places which are very close to each other or on top of each other meaning you will have overlap; and you don't want a cluster of individual pins near to each other all referring to the same place.

In that case, you will want to look into something like [Google Maps Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id) which assigns a unique identifier to each "place" on Google maps. For instance in your database you you could store a Place ID as a string of "ChIJFZo6iUSVwoARNU6w60iDGqY" (the In-N-Out Burger in Burbank California).

Other mapping services will have their own equivalents.